# How can I be notified when collection-type DP is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.

I have created as following a behavior that working at the TextBox control.
The behavior has a collection-type DP named Items.

```
class HighlightBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{

public List<TextStyle>Items
{
    get { return (List<TextStyle>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(List<TextStyle>), typeof(HighlightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(ItemsChanged));

private static void ItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // break point 
}

}
```

And... I have created a MainWindow to use as following code above behavior.

```
<MainWindow>
  <TextBox>
    <i:interaction.Behaviors>
      <behavior:HighlightBehavior/>
    </i:interaction.Behavior>
  </TextBox>
</MainWindow>
```

And I have written a MainWindowViewModel that has a collection-type DP named HighlightItems.

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<TextStyle> HighlightItems
    {
        get { return (List<TextStyle>)GetValue(HighlightItemsProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightItemsProperty , value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightItems", typeof(List<TextStyle>), typeof(HighlightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SetValue(HighlightItemsProperty, new List<TextStyle>());
    }
}
```

And I have bound the MainWindowViewModel to MainWindow and connected HighlightItems(DP) of MainWindowViewModel with Items(DP) of HighlightBehavior as the following code.

```
<MainWindow>
  <TextBox>
    <i:interaction.Behaviors>
      <behavior:HighlightBehavior Items="{Binding HighlightItems, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </i:interaction.Behavior>
  </TextBox>
</MainWindow>
```

To sum up, the structure is the following figure.

[image]

I have expected that ItemsChanged of HighlightBehavior is called whenever Items changed.
But it is not called.

I want to get notification whenever collection-type DP(Items) of HighlightBehavior is changed.
What must I do to reach this goal?

Thank you for reading.
I'll wait for an answer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: In your XAML, you have `Items="{Binding HighlightBehavior}"`. Is that a typo? I would expect it to be `Items="{Binding HighlightItems}"`.

Comment: Yes Items="{Binding HighlightItems}.
That is correct.

Comment: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/… 
Just now,  I followed instructions on the site above but still, I don't receive a notification when Items(DP of HighlightBehavior) is changed.

Comment: Do you want a notification when the entire collection is replaced (i.e. the DP is set), or when an item is added/removed from the collection?

Comment: I've no idea what happens if you just give it a method signature like your code. I would always explicitly use new PropertyChangedCallback(method). Instead of  new PropertyMetadata(ItemsChanged).  That might address your issue but all that will tell you is when the entire property is set. Not changes to the collection.

Comment: Do you want a notification when the entire collection is replaced (i.e. the DP is set), or when an item is added/removed from the collection?
-> Yes I want it.

Comment: *Which* one do you want? "Notification when the entire collection is replaced" or "notification when an item is added/removed from the collection?" (Or both?).

Comment: The "notification when an item is added/removed from the collection" case more appropriate for me but if possible I want to know both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). This is a special type of collection which raises its `CollectionChanged` event whenever an item is added, removed, changed or moved.

I recommend the following:

1. Instead of declaring `HighlightItems` as `List<TextStyle>`, declare it as `ObservableCollection<TextStyle>`.
2. Add another method to `HighlightBehavior` to handle `CollectionChanged`, for example:
   `HighlightItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)`
3. Your current implementation of `ItemsChanged` will be called whenever `HighlightItems` is set. Use that to attach an event handler to `CollectionChanged` like so:

```
var col = (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)e.NewValue;
if (col != null) { col.CollectionChanged += HighlightItemsCollectionChanged; }
```

4. Don't forget to remove any existing event handler to the previous collection in case `HighlightItems` is set move than once. You can add this to `ItemsChanged` along with the previous snippet:

```
col = (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)e.OldValue;
if (col != null) { col.CollectionChanged -= HighlightItemsCollectionChanged; }
```

5. `HighlightItemsCollectionChanged` will now be called whenever an item is added or removed from `HighlightItems`. Do whatever you need to do in this method, or if you want the code to also run when the collection itself is replaced, you can make another method that actually does what you want, and then call that method from both `ItemsChanged` and `HighlightItemsCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the code following your advice and now I can receive a notification when the element of the collection is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I have changed the code following your advice and now I can receive a notification when the element of the collection is changed.

I knew about the ObservableCollection but I didn't know how to use right about CollectionChanged event.

In fact, previous I tried to use the ObservableCollection and registered the CollectionChanged delegate method at the Constructer as following but it is not called.

```
public ObservableCollection<TextStyle> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<TextStyle>), typeof(HighlightBehavior),
          new PropertyMetaData(null));

public HighlightBehavior()
{
    SetValue(ItemsProperty, new ObservableCollection<TextStyle>());
    Items.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // The code when the collection is changed.
}
```

Now, I have registered the CollectionChanged delegate method in the PropertyChangedCallback method as following and it(OnCollectionChanged method at the following code) is called.

```
public ObservableCollection<TextStyle> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<TextStyle>), typeof(HighlightBehavior),
          new PropertyMetaData(ItemsChanged));

private static void ItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var col = (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)e.NewValue;
    if (col != null) { col.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged; ; }

    col = (ObservableCollection<TextStyle>)e.OldValue;
    if (col != null) { col.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged; }
}

public HighlightBehavior()
{
    SetValue(ItemsProperty, new ObservableCollection<TextStyle>());
}
```

Thank you for your answer in detail.